# Increase cell value that contains number and text VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried this code which works fine for a cell that only contain number:

```
Sub IncreaseCellValue()
    'Add 1 to the existing cell value
    Range("A1").Value = Range("A1") + 1
End Sub
```

How can I do something similar if the cell has text and a number. For example, I have "Apple 1" and I want to "increase" the cell text to "Apple 2" and next time I run the macro I want "Apple 3".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way you could solve this problem:

```
Sub IncreaseCellValue()
    Dim value As Variant

    'Add 1 to the existing cell value

    If IsNumeric(Range("A1").value) Then
       Range("A1").value = Range("A1") + 1
    Else
       value = Split(Range("A1").value, " ")
       Range("A1").value = value(0) & " " & (CInt(value(1)) + 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

It will cover the 2 cases you presented in your question but not every scenario you could throw at it.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for :)!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following function

```
Sub IncreaseCellValue()
    'Add 1 to the existing cell value
    Range("A1").Value = Replace(Range("A1").Value2, CleanString(Range("A1")), vbNullString) & CInt(CleanString(Range("A1").Value2)) + 1
End Sub
```

---

```
Function CleanString(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
     .Global = True
     .Pattern = "[^\d]+"
    CleanString = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

please check:

```
Option Explicit


Sub IncreaseCellValue()
    'Add 1 to the existing cell value

    Dim rg As Range

    Set rg = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)



  Range("A1" & ":" & rg.Address).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1" & ":" & rg.Offset(1, 0).Address), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you may try something like this...

```
Function GetNumber(ByVal rng As Range) As Long
Dim i As Long
For i = Len(rng.Value) To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(Mid(rng.Value, i, 1)) Then
        GetNumber = GetNumber & Mid(rng.Value, i, 1)
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Function

Sub IncrementNumber()
Dim num As Long
num = GetNumber(Range("A1"))
Range("A1").Value = Replace(Range("A1").Value, num, num + 1)
End Sub
```